# The code alone works, but when i import webbrowser, even if it doesn't have nothing to do with it

Tags: python, typeerror, configparser

Obviously it's part of a big application but that's the minimal reproducible example
The code should save something in config.ini but I can't manage to make it work when it goes into the whole app:

That's the working code:

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# Add the structure to the file we will create
config.add_section('pos')
config.set('pos', 'x', '0')
config.set('pos', 'y', '0')

# Write the new structure to the new file
with open(r"C:/Users/gberg/Desktop/main/coding/config.ini", 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
from webbrowser import *
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# Add the structure to the file we will create
config.add_section('pos')
config.set('pos', 'x', '0')
config.set('pos', 'y', '0')

# Write the new structure to the new file
with open(r"C:/Users/gberg/Desktop/main/coding/config.ini", 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

The error i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\gberg\Desktop\main\coding\frog_prova.py", line 19, in <module>
    with open(r"C:/Users/gberg/Desktop/main/coding/config.ini", 'w') as configfile:
TypeError: 'bool' object does not support the context manager protocol
```

I tried different ways of using configparser but I always get the same error.
Even using
`config.write(open(r"C:/Users/gberg/Desktop/main/coding/config.ini", 'w'))`
instead of

```
with open(r"C:/Users/gberg/Desktop/main/coding/config.ini", 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

still causes problems.
Please help me

Comment: You should avoid using `*` imports whenever possible (i.e. almost always). The [webbrowser module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open) has its own `open` function which is shadowing the builtin one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overridden built-in `open` with `webbrowser.open`:

```
>>> open('/tmp/fname', 'w')
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/tmp/fname' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> from webbrowser import *
>>> open('/tmp/fname', 'w')
True
```

Solution: avoid asterisk imports (`from X import *`) like plague.